# stop windows from accessing linux directories

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, laptop

I have a `laptop` with hybrid hdd (1Tb) and ssd (500Gb)
I want to have dual boot windows and linux. Os files on ssd and storage files on hdd
so I have to make partitions that only ubuntu can access and other that only windows can access
on both hdd and ssd. Is it possible and if not what other thing is possible? I just want to use two pc on one completely separate
from each other.  I wanna tell you that I want to do this because if in future I get any virus on windows partition  it will not effect my linux and any personal files (Important files would not be lost). Please help me with the problem.

Comment: Is your goal limited to protecting your files in the event of a virus? If so, having more than operating system is not a solution … 

Comment: If you use a Linux filesystem for Ubuntu Windows will not be able to read it. If you don’t mount your Windows partitions Ubuntu will not be able to read those. A virus can mess up your EFI partition so as @matigo says two operating systems will not be a full solution. You need antivirus and data backups to be safe

Comment: The best thing to do is search on YouTube or Google for “install Ubuntu. That will give you a good idea of the process

Comment: Thanks Buddy The community is so good.

Comment: @PonJar: Windows can't read Linux filesystems by default, but there are tools like _Explore2fs_ or the _Ext2IFS_ Windows driver to access _some_ filesystem types. It's not a problem when dealing with kids at play, but it's not safe against a determined attacker.

Comment: @Free Down: Using encrypted partitions (LUKS with or without LVM) is safe. Unless we are talking about agencies like the NSA or the FSB (ex KGB), of course; they may have a different class of tools at their displosal. ;-)

Comment: @Free Down: Please also consider that a virus is only _one_ kind of disaster that can happen. More common are hardware failures (disk or controller dies) or human error a.k.a. one's own stupidity. There is just no substitute to regular backups of anything that you put work into, i.e. your own documents, photos or other files that mean something to you.